# Same code, different variables, doesn't work?

Tags: python, loops, nested-loops

```
compass=[student.strip() for student in open("compassfeb8.txt",'U')]
roster=[student.strip() for student in open("feb4py.txt",'U')]
dropped=False
for name in compass:
    if name not in roster:
        print name
        dropped=True

if not dropped:
    print "Hooray! Nobody dropped."
```

This code does not work. However, the following code does:

```
roster1=[student.strip() for student in open("jan24py.txt",'U')]
roster2=[student.strip() for student in open("feb4py.txt",'U')]
new_students=False
for name in roster2:
    if name not in roster1:
        print name
        new_students=True

if not new_students:
    print "There were no new students."
```

For the first code block, I'm trying to figure out which students are still users on our class website but are not on the official roster taken from the University, so that we can drop them from the class website.

The second code block checks if we have new students.

This is quite embarrassing, but I cannot figure out how to indent when pasting my code in. (I'm learning HTML in the coming weeks.) But, I believe all of my indentations are correct.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. There's a wealth of information available at the top of the post window when you create one to help you with formatting. To format code simply highlight it an click the `{}` button; there's no need to add loads of `<br>` yourself.

Comment: You're not comparing apples to apples here; you have a file in your first, non-working example that isn't present in your second, working example.

Comment: This isn't quite the same code. `roster` in your first example and `roster2` in your second are used differently... you use `compass` in your first instead.

Comment: The code looks fine, did any of the students actually drop? I'd suggest manually creating a student that 'dropped' just to test that it works.

Comment: as an aside, you can create a list of new students in `new_students` instead of testing each one and throwing it away. Do `new_students = [name for name in compass if name not in roster]` then you can check `bool(new_students)` which is `True` if there are any students and `False` if it's empty.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am aware it is not *exactly* the same code and that I use compass/roster instead of roster1/roster1, and different .txt files. What I meant by "same code" was that they should do the same thing; compare two .txt files and tell me which students are not present in the one that I specify. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: One detail I should have mentioned - it prints the entire class list. I don't know if it is pulling from the roster file or the compass file when it does this. @frmdrstryr we have a "demo user" on compass, so if no one dropped, the demo user should print if this works correctly. And, actually, I think I figured out what the problem is. The .txts aren't the same - in the roster .txt, their names are last, first and surrounded by quotes. In the compass .txt, it is first, last and no quotes...

Answer (score 1):

You've not only changed the variable names, you've also changed the nesting of the statements. Flip the variable names in the `for` and `if` statements on the one that doesn't work.

Comment: @user2809707: Erm, no. One is "compass", the other is "roster".

Comment: I thought you were talking about "name." Isn't that a variable, too?

Comment: Nevermind. That's not the problem. The .txt files aren't formatted in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this. Create the names as set, and then use the [set.difference](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html#set-objects) function to find new\dropped students.

```
compass={student.strip() for student in open("compassfeb8.txt",'U')}
roster={student.strip() for student in open("feb4py.txt",'U')}

dropped_students = compass.difference(roster)

if not dropped_students:
    print "Hooray! Nobody dropped."

roster1={student.strip() for student in open("jan24py.txt",'U')}
# roster2={student.strip() for student in open("feb4py.txt",'U')}
roster2 = roster

new_students = roster2.difference(roster1)

if not new_students:
    print "There were no new students."
```

Comment: My programming prof suggested this, but we haven't gotten there in class yet, so I didn't want to get ahead of myself. =)